# access model from view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

can anyone tell me how do i access model from view in codeigniter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Load a model on the controller

```
$this->load->model('yourmodel');
```

Assign this model to a var like this

```
$data['model_obj'] = $this->yourmodel;
```

and assign this data array to your view template

Use $model_obj object on the view template for calling model methods

```
$model_obj->some_method()
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Works perfect!

Comment: very nice answer .

Comment: This is what exactly i was looking for.. seems like millions of year has been saved

Comment: You shouldn't be calling Model from View though. That's against MVC model. You should keep business logic separate from View.

Answer (score 7):

You can use following code:

```php
$ci = &get_instance();
$ci->load->model('your_model');
$ci->your_model->your_function();
```

Note: You have to call your model in your controller. Its working fine

Comment: Thanx bro ..@Pritam Chaudhari

Answer (score 6):

See the thread:

[**View Calling a Model**](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/86128/#433862)

By the way why do you need to access the `model` from the `view`, you can send the model data to the view from the `controller` too which is the usual and better approach.

As a good note, keep your processing logic out of the view, you should use `controller` instead.

Comment: nothings here notes that there is processing in the view. In MVC, the view has access to the model. See: http://www.phpwact.org/pattern/model_view_controller

Comment: ok then how do i access 3 tables using controller-model method? i had to select data from 3 tables and all of them depends in the value generated from 1st query, is there any other easy way, i was successful to create join in 2 tables but no idea in 3 tables joins, any suggestion?

Comment: Broken Link. Codeigniter changed their forums around.

Answer (score 6):

CodeIgniter's `$this->load->model()` returns absolutely nothing. Look at it: `system/libraries/Loader.php`.

This will output absolutely nothing:

```
$model = $this->load->model('table');

print_r($model);
```

And this next example will give you the fatal error `Call to a member function some_func() on a non-object`:

```
$model = $this->load->model('table');

$model->some_func();
```

It doesn't matter whether that function even exists, `$model` is not an object.

The thing to do is have a method in your model that returns data, then call that function and pass the results to your view file:

```
$this->load->model('table');
$data = $this->table->some_func();
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

*PS: How is the only answer you've accepted the absolute wrong thing to do?*

Comment: @ bschaeffer - i am loading model than after i call function. but it give me an error "Call to a member function addPost() on a non-object"

Comment: there is a way to do it i found by accident, but it is a security whole to do so, models are suppose handle accessing the database and organizing the data, the controller is should handle any type of logic of data manipulation, and is a go between between for the view and the models, this helps prevent direct access to your data from public pages and centralizes and manipulation of the data decreasing the time it takes to debug

Answer (score 2):

In cases when you want to access a model function from within a shared view , you don't have to load the needed model in every controller that will call that view. you can load the model **inside the view itself** by using the following code :

```
   $ci =&get_instance();
   $ci->load->model(model_name);
   $ci->model_name->function_name();
```

in older versions of codeigniter the following code used to work :

```
$this->load->model('model_name'); 
model_name::function();
```

but when tested on CI 3.1.9 it throw the following error 
**Message:  Undefined property: CI_Loader::$model_name_model**

**Note:** I use this technique in template views (sidebar, menus ...etc) which is not used everywhere in my application , if you want to access a model from anywhere in your application considre loading this model globally by adding it to the autoload array in **application/config/autoload.php**

Answer (score 1):

Since $model is not an object, you can make a call to the model "table" using "::" scope resolution operator, which can call the function of the class itself without any object instance.

```
$this->load->model('table'); 
table::some_funct();
```

Note: you also need to make the function "some_funct" static inside your model "table".

Answer (score 0):

Hey. You can access from view to models the same mode as you access on its controller. Remember that the view access to models that import its controller.

Answer (score 0):

in the original UML I've seem for MVC architecture, view calls methods in model..

http://www.as3dp.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/mvc_pope_krasner.png

..but in practice with PHP apps, because there is no persistence to track state changes in objects between requests (or at least not efficiently),  I find it better to keep all model method calls in controller and pass the result to view if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your model's name to config -> autoload model

```
$autoload['model'] = array('model_name');
```

this success for me

Answer (score -2):

You can access basicly a method from view in codeingiter.

```
public function index()
{

    $this->load->model('persons');
    $data['mydata'] = $this->persons->getAllSessionData();
    $this->load->view('test_page', $data);
}
```

in view

```
print_r ($mydata);
```

my function returned an array.

Comment: You don't access the model from the view. You access it from the controller and provides the output to the view. It's not what is asked by the author of the question.