# PHP and Codeigniter - How do you check if a model exists and/or not throw an error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

### Example #1

`bschaeffer's`answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719876/access-model-from-view-in-codeigniter) question - in his last example:

```
$this->load->model('table');
$data = $this->table->some_func();
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

How do you handle this when `'table'` doesn't exist?

---

### Example #2

```
    try {
        $this->load->model('serve_' . $model_name, 'my_model');
        $this->my_model->my_fcn($prams);

        // Model Exists

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Model does NOT Exist
    }
```

But still after running this (obvously the model doesn't exist - but sometimes will) it fails with the following error:

> **An Error Was Encountered**
>
> Unable to locate the model you have specified: serve_forms

---

I am getting this function call by:

1) Getting some JSON:

> ```
> "model_1:{"function_name:{"pram_1":"1", "pram_2":"1"}}
> ```

2) And turning it into the function call:

> $this->load->model('serve_' . "model_1", 'my_model');

3) Where I call:

> ```
> $this->my_model->function_name(pram_1=1, pram_2=1);
> ```

---

### SOLUTION

The problem lies in the fact that CodeIgniter's `show_error(...)` function displays the error then `exit;` ... Not cool ... So I overrode: `model(...)` -> `my_model(..)` (you'll get errors if you just override it) and removed the `show_error(...)` because for some reason you can't override it - weird for Codeigniter). Then in `my_model(...)` made it throw an Exception

> **My personal opinion:** the calling function should `return
>   show_error("message");` where show_error returns `FALSE` --- that or
>   you could take out the `exit;` - and make `show_error(...)`
>   overridable

Comment: given that you have to manually put the model name somewhere in your code, why would you try and load a model where you know the file doesn't exist?  CI 2.x's package paths will allow you to very easily distribute your models among a directory structure.

Comment: I'm trying to give one model the ability to get data from other models. E.X.- I want HTML from `model_1`, JSON: `"model_1:{"pram_1":"1", "pram_2":"1"}` -> `$this->load->model('serve_' . "model_1", 'my_model');` Trying to build this system to be expandable

Comment: My point still stands, you've programmed the "model_1" into your code somewhere, why not just make it at the server and have a bunch of small wrapper functions in your controller.  Either way, the only situation in which a model might not exist is if the required model is somehow requested via user generated content which would be mildly insane...

Comment: I see what you're saying - the problem is that I try and make it so programers, that are not as anal about errors as me, can build stuff into the system ... in this case there is a chance that a 'non-programer' could change the original JSON string so error handling is essential (at least in the early release of this particular piece of software)

Comment: If you haven't already, invest some time into looking at alternative architecture solutions.  It sounds like you're heading for real problems later.  Codeigniter already provides a really robust way of accessing controllers and their functions, it sounds like you're just trying to push this access a level deeper to the models rather than write some short clean wrappers in your controllers.  If it makes the code easier to maintain, it's ok to write more lines of code, a little extra really isn't going to affect performance noticeably.

Comment: p.s. Have a look at how PyroCMS (which uses CI) handles developer extension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can see if the file exists in the models folder.

```
$model = 'my_model';
if(file_exists(APPPATH."models/$model.php")){
   $this->load->model($model);
   $this->my_model->my_fcn($prams);
}
else{
  // model doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: This makes sense (and may be how I have to solve this problem) but this function is used in generating a page that is going to be used **a lot** - I see this killing the server by forcing it to make this query every time it has to generate the page... Also, I would rather not tie all my models into one folder here - eventually I am planning on further separating my models and don't want to have to worry about where the file is located.

Comment: @Walter: You kinda need to know where the file is in order to load it.

Comment: @Rocket the models map can have subdirectories where the models are located. In that case you need to edit your piece of code.

Comment: @Vince2doom: `if(file_exists(APPPATH.'models/subfolder/my_model.php')){`.  In order to load the model, you need to know the subdirectory, so I don't why that's an issue.

Comment: @Rocket true. I thought the load->model() function would just fail silently.

Comment: @Rocket: I understand what your saying, and I recognize your answer solves the problem, but I would like to use the Codeigniter Framework that handles all of the file locating vs re-inventing the wheel --- also this code is going to be used in an environment where all the files are not necessarily located on the same server

Comment: @Walter: If the files aren't on the same server, how can you load the model?  By the way, here's the code that CodeIngiter uses to load models: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/252e9c8091cc/system/core/Loader.php#cl-201

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helper function will help you to check if a model is loaded or not.

```
function is_model_loaded($model)
{
    $ci =& get_instance();      
    $load_arr = (array) $ci->load;

    $mod_arr = array();
    foreach ($load_arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if (substr(trim($key), 2, 50) == "_ci_models")
            $mod_arr = $value;
    }
    //print_r($mod_arr);die;

    if (in_array($model, $mod_arr))
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

[source reference](http://arif.suparlan.com/2012/10/29/codeigniter-fungsi-helper-cek-model-telah-di-load)

Answer (score 1):

Don't foget that your application may use pakages. This helper function look through all models (even in packages included in your CI app).

```
if ( ! function_exists('model_exists')){
    function model_exists($name){
        $CI = &get_instance();
        foreach($CI->config->_config_paths as $config_path)if(file_exists(FCPATH . $config_path . 'models/' . $name . '.php'))return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I used this as a basis for my solution. Since I already have a MY_Loader class which I use to add different directories in which to store models, I added a new method to that class:

Comment: [edit timeout]

`function model_exists($name){
        $CI = &get_instance();
        foreach($this->_ci_model_paths as $config_path)if(file_exists(FCPATH . $config_path . 'models/' . $name . '.php'))return true;
        return false;
    }`

As to 'how could you possibly not know if your model file exists?', a framework with site specific models and extensions that may not be appropriate for adding to core files but may exist.

Answer (score 0):

@Endophage  No you do not have to explicitly state what the model you are loading will be.  They can be loaded dynamically.
Example:

```
$path = 'path/to/model/';
$model = 'My_model';
$method = '_my_method'; 
$this->load->model($path . $model);
return $this->$model->$method();
```

So you could have a single controller that uses the URL or POST vars.

I use this concept a lot with ajax calls.  So OP's question is very valid.  I would like to make sure that the model exists before I try to load it.