# Code Igniter:Navigation(View) to Model:Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property:

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, model

UPDATE:

```
$ci =&get_instance();
$ci->load->model(your model);
$ci->(your model)->(your function);     
Note: You have to call your model in your controller.Its working fine
```

Using above answer from ([access model from view in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719876/access-model-from-view-in-codeigniter))

My above code should work. But why it does not.
I am loading my menu in navigation using database. Im connecting directly from my model. In my navigation I have

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('masterdata/MasterDataRole_','masterdatarole');
$menu = $CI->masterdatarole->loadMenu();
```

In my `masterdata/MasterDataRole_` I have

```
<?php
class MasterDataRole_ extends CI_Model{
    //menu

    //submenu

    //screen

    //check access rights
    public function hasAccess($page_id,$level){
        $query = $this->db->select('RoleAccess')
                ->from('masterdatarolemapping')
                ->where('ItemLevel',$level)
                ->where('ItemSysID',$page_id)
                ->where('MasterDataRoleID',$this->session->userdata('UserID'))
                ->get();
        if($query){
            if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                $data = $query->row();
                return $data->access;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But I get error saying

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: MasterDataRole::$menu
>
> Filename: templates/navigation.php
>
> Line Number: 117

In my Navigation I have:

```
<?php foreach ($menu as $m): echo $m;?>
    <?php if($CI->menu->hasAccess($m->SysID,'menu') == 'yes'): ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any Idea is appreciated.

`UPDATE`

error is on this `<?php if($CI->menu->hasAccess($m->SysID,'menu') == 'yes'): ?>`

this line `<?php foreach ($menu as $m): echo $m;?>` give the list of menu

Answer (score 0):

```
$CI->load->model('masterdata/MasterDataRole_','masterdatarole');
$menu = $CI->masterdatarole->loadMenu();
```

Should be `masterdatarole` not `menu`